# Upgrading xubuntu broke brazilian keyboard

Tags: upgrade, keyboard, xubuntu

I upgraded by xubuntu notebook to 11.10 and accents in my brazilian keyboard
no longer work. They work neither in the basic Brazilian keyboard layout
nor does the compose key work in the nodeadkeys layout.

Answer (score 2):

Xfce Goodies Project has a plugin that allows you to setup and use multiple keyboard layouts:

[panel-plugins: xfce4-xkb-plugin](http://goodies.xfce.org/projects/panel-plugins/xfce4-xkb-plugin)

> It enables a convenient way of changing keyboard layouts and showing currently active layout on the xfce4-panel. It also makes install for keyboard layouts available and setting default keyboard change shortcut in a easy way.

Install and use it to change you keyboard layout to Brazilian.

**Note:**

There's a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xfce4-xkb-plugin/+bug/548631) where users report that the plugin resets all the settings (languages used and a switch layouts hotkey) every time the system gets rebooted.

If it happens to you, there's already a work around at this [askubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/83942/63174).

Answer (score -4):

Make the br keyboard layout default.

Comment: I did not down vote your answer, but you should describe how to make the br keyboard the default.