# Is synapse application launcher available?

Tags: synapse

I really like that synapse application launcher, but there seems to be no way of installing it in ubuntu 14.04. Any ideas why? Or does anyone know how I could get it?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

[A bug has been filed](https://bugs.launchpad.net/synapse-project/+bug/1288839) on launchpad about that.

It seems, though, that the program's testing PPA now supports 14.04: 
[Synapse Bleeding edge](https://launchpad.net/~synapse-core/+archive/testing)

---

**EDIT**:

To install from the PPA above, do the following in a terminal - [<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>]

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:synapse-core/testing
```

*(press* <kbd>Enter</kbd>-key *when prompted to continue)*

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install synapse
```

Synapse should now be installed.

**NOTE**: It is not recommended that you use a bleeding edge version of a software application as they may (and often do) contain game breaking bugs. My advice is that you keep checking Ubuntu's software repository and revert to a stable version as soon as one is made available.

Comment: thanks for the info. I just simply dont know how to install an application from that source.

Comment: @Elysium: added install instructions.

Comment: thanks Miguel. I marked it as an answer. I also agree with the comment below...."install" is missing from the last line.

Comment: @Elysium, absolutely. Apologies for the mistake.

Comment: Just in case anyone else is reading this and curious about the new one's functionality: I just installed it like miguel detailed it above and am happy to report: it's working as the "old" Synapse did in 13.10. Wohoo. :)

Comment: UPDATE: there is now also stable PPA with packages for Trusty: https://launchpad.net/~synapse-core/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

Answer (score 5):

Synapse was [removed of Debian](https://bugs.debian.org/739131) since was [seriously bugged](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=713655) and blocked the removal of Vala, this also affects new Ubuntu installation since Ubuntu imports from Debian.

You can use a PPA or compiling from sources but you wont have Ubuntu support to solve any bug encountered.

[The changelog of the package confirms this.](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/synapse/+changelog)

Comment: Is there a good alternative to synapse?

Comment: @Shah I don't know, I don't use the software, I just check the reasons why was it removed from the repositories.

Comment: @Shah Not AFAIK, however as stated by other users in this thread the PPA for 64 bit seems to work without problems.

Answer (score 4):

I've been looking for Synapse too, since I installed Ubuntu 14.04, and just found these links:

For 32-bit PC:
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/i386/synapse/0.2.10-2ubuntu3
Look for "synapse_0.2.10-2ubuntu3_i386.deb (473.5 KiB)" under Downloadable files.

For 64-bit PC:
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/amd64/synapse/0.2.10-2ubuntu3
Look for "synapse_0.2.10-2ubuntu3_amd64.deb (475.9 KiB)" under Downloadable files.

Attention! I still haven't tested them, for I'm at work right now. As soon as I get home, in the evening, I'll test it, then I come back here to say if it works or not. In the meantime, if anyone tests it, please, let us know if it works, OK?

I hope this works. I really miss Synapse. Unity Dash sucks! :)

Comment: I tested Synapse for 64-bit and it works just fine...

Comment: As I promised, here I am again, with my feedback. I've tested the 64-bit version and it works! I recommend it. I hope this this piece of information is helpful. Cheers, guys. :)

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to Synapse which is available in the Software Center is called Launchy.  It's not quite as nice as Synapse but does the trick and doesn't seem to break anything.

Answer (score 1):

Gnome-do will do.

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-do
```

Comment: This is great..

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the Bleeding Edge PPA:

ppa:synapse-core/testing

It contains Synapse for Ubuntu 14.04.

(Original answer not mine. I found it here: [How to add ppa repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217179/how-to-add-ppa-repositories)). It works!

Comment: answered in [@miguelg's answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/449287/283843).

Answer (score 1):

I have found several users having problems with the bleeding edge version of synapse. Sometimes it doesn't run. I have included a .deb file to share which is version 0.2.10, I have not had any issues with this version on several machines. Link below to download.

http://xellink.com/2015/01/31/lubuntu-guide-synapse-application-launcher/

Answer (score -1):

Synapse is no longer officially maintained; so in my eyes there is not much sense in trying to somehow get it up and running on your system. You might be better of using alternatives, like "launchy" or "kupfer".

Comment: Or the original, GNOME Do ☺

Comment: Erv not maintained? I see both repos still getting updates: https://launchpad.net/~synapse-core/+archive/ubuntu/ppa, https://launchpad.net/~synapse-core/+archive/ubuntu/testing

Comment: Synapse is still developed. I choose Kupfer as an alternative, though.