# Find and remove a system-wide keyboard shortcut

Tags: 14.04, shortcut-keys

After updating to Xubuntu 14.04 the other day, I noticed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> stopped working in both Eclipse and NetBeans, but I cannot find where it's bound. Nor does it appear to do anything.

I have looked in the **Settings Manager** on the **Keyboard**, **Window Manager**, and **Settings Editor** (XFCE-specific) applets, but none of the commands are bound to that combination. Is there another applet that defines system-wide shortcuts?

Comment: Do you have `synapse` installed? Synapse natively uses ctrl + space.

Comment: @Parto `dpkg -s synapse` gives `dpkg-query: package 'synapse' is not installed and no information is available`. I never installed it before, and [it doesn't seem to be available for 14.04](http://askubuntu.com/a/449287/18031) yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [bug thread](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ibus/+bug/1278569), one of the recent versions of `ibus` was either added in 14.04 or added a new key binding for switching input methods. Luckily, [removing the binding](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2207330) is trivial.

1. Run `ibus-setup` from the command line
2. Click <kbd>...</kbd> to the far right of **Next input method**
3. Click **Delete**
4. Click **OK**
5. Click **Close**

> Note to future self: Never dismiss the most obvious search query—"ubuntu 14.04 ctrl-space"—without trying it first!